# Should Community wiki answers converted via editing still be granting rep to the original answerer?

Tags: bug, reputation, community-wiki

My answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46215/23562) got put into community wiki status automatically because I edited it lots (I was also the only editor).

From my understanding, once an answer becomes a community wiki, the original answerer no longer receives rep from upvotes to the answer, but I am still receiving reputation on upvotes to that answer since it went to wiki (It went to wiki on June 11, 22:13Z, but I got an upvote rep from it on June 18, 18:19Z).

Does that not apply to answers that received wiki status via mass-editing when all the editing was done by the original answerer or is this a bug?

Comment: Huh.  I heard some rumblings about this changing but I thought the CW status would not be applied if you were still to receive rep.  It's a good answer, so I upvoted it now, and your rep hasn't changed.  I'm not sure I would reverse the CW-ization though since many of the edits were minor ... we don't want it continually bumped to the first page for that.

Comment: @MatthewRead maybe I don't understand the point of CW, but shouldn't things only go to CW if multiple people edit it? the 10 edit rule seems arbitrary, especially if someone keeps updating their answer in a short period of time (in this case, 24-48 hours). Maybe 10 edits over a longer period of time or multiple people would make sense to me... but I don't know what the StackExchange view is on this.

Comment: @BryanDenny Even the folks at SE don't understand CW and never have :P.  It's in a really weird limbo right now.  I've previously expanded on my take over at Music: [http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/a/14/28](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/a/14/28)

Comment: The reason posts go CW after 10 edits from the author is to help prevent authors from continually bumping their post to the front page.